# Github Action Docker Build and Push not working

Tags: docker, ssh, github-actions, docker-build, docker-push

I am trying to build a simple Dockerfile using build and push but no matter what I do it gives me permission errors. Here is the Github Action Yaml (we are running on a large runner since it is a large image):

```
name: Build Image and Push to ACR
on:
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest-4-cores
    steps:
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      - name: "Azure Login using AZURE_CREDENTIALS Secret"
        uses: azure/login@v1.1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
      - name: "Docker login"
        run: |
          az account set --subscription ${{ secrets.SUBSCRIPTION_ID}}
          docker login crappdev.azurecr.io -u ${{ secrets.ACR_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.ACR_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Prepare Key
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.7.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      - name: "Build and push image"
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: crappdev.azurecr.io/mycompany/myimage:0.0.${{ github.run_number }},crappdev.azurecr.io/mycompany/myimage:latest
          build-args: |
            TAG=${{ vars.TAG }}
            SHA=${{ vars.SHA }}
          ssh: |
            default=${{ env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK }}
```

I have all the variables defined. I added a repository key and added the private key as a secret. I tested the key manually to make sure I can check out this (and only this) repository with git. I already used `ssh-keyscan` to add Github to the `known_hosts` in myuser's `.ssh` directory

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
ARG TAG
FROM crappdev.azurecr.io/mycompany/mybase:${TAG}

USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser
RUN --mount=type=ssh,id=default cd /opt/envs/myvenv/ && \
   pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git@${SHA} 


ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "--"]
```

Most of the heavy lifting is in the base image. For this repo I just want to add it to the virtual-env which is defined for my user in base image. Its important to `pip install` it as source, so it makes use of some patched versions of libraries in the base (mostly NVidia's own torch from their Torch image).

When I run the CI on Github I get the following error:

```
 > [stage-0 3/3] RUN --mount=type=ssh,id=default cd /opt/envs/myenv/ &&    pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git@$***SHA***:
#6 3.262 Collecting git+ssh://****@github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git@
#6 3.263   Cloning ssh://****@github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-ilthmk_v
#6 3.263   Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-ilthmk_v
#6 3.335   Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '123.45.678.9' to the list of known hosts.
#6 3.385   git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
#6 3.386   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#6 3.386 
#6 3.386   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#6 3.386   and the repository exists.
```

As noted I manually tested the ssh key on this repo, so I know 100% it can git clone it.

This line worries me a bit:
`#6 3.262 Collecting git+ssh://****@github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git@`
Why is it empty after the @ since the `SHA` variable is defined, or is that just Github being secure?

Is the problem I am running as `myuser` not `root`?

Something else I am missing here?

Comment: `SHA` is defined under `vars` so it should have a value in plain text. The secrets are redacted. You need to add a separate step to verify that `vars.SHA` has the valid value.

Comment: Also, please confirm that you're not using an [environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment).

Comment: @Azeem thanks for your suggestions. I made two changes to the Dockerfile - one is I did and echo on the SHA. This was interesting because it showed "2.5" instead of the hex value of the SHA. I will try with quotes. At the same time I removed the SHA value completely from the `pip install` statement. It should have checked out the top level but instead I got the same fatal error. Just in case I tried the `pip install` with and without the SHA in my shell and it worked fine. I am not using environments

Comment: Right. Another thing that I noticed is that there is not code checkout step in your workflow. Why is that?

Comment: @azeem  because Docker's build and push automatically checks out itself so no need. If it didn't I wouldn't have the Dockerfile available :)

Comment: Right. Yes, I got that part. Just wanted to confirm.